# How to design my database?About edit history

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database-design

I want to create a very simple database. But I want to know the edit history!

Obviously, we have:

```
Product

title | price | created_at | updated_at
```

In my opinion, I add the 'edition' column to the table.The edition's default is 1.

When I use Rails and edit the `price` column, it will create a new record and the 'edition' will increase.

Example:

```
Product

TITLE | PRICE | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | EDITION
Plane | 12    | 9-19       | NULL       | 1
```

When I edit, a record should be created like this:

```
Product

TITLE | PRICE | CREATED_AT | UPDATED_AT | EDITION
Plane | 8     | 9-20       | NULL       | 2
```

But I don't know how to select the data when I want to know the new edition 'plane' product.
When I search the edit history can use the code ,like

```
scope :history, lambda { |tit| where(:title => tit) } //same title
```

I don't think this is a best design.

And do you suggest any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest edit map is actually just to store the old data in another table:

```
Product_History
-- Note: We have added a surrogate primary key
-- This makes it possible to have duplicate product titles
-- which we may wish to support later.
-- It's just an auto-incrementing integer column. 
Product_ID | Title | Price | Created_At | Updated_At | Updated_By
```

Then you simply dump the old values in the Product_History table every time you make an update to the Product table.

The slightly more flexible way is to store the data in an even more denormalized state:

```
Edit_History

Table_Name | Entity_ID | Previous_Value | Current_Value | Edit_Date | Edited_By
```

This second variant can be used for recording changes to multiple tables. (Please note, this assumes you don't have compound primary keys).

In both of these cases you simply query the Product table whenever you want to know the latest value and you query the History table using the primary key of your Product table (combined with the 'Product' table name in the `Edit_History` variant) when you want to know the history of the changes that this entity has gone through.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got good answers about database design, I just want to add my 5 cents and advise you not to reinvent the wheel and implement common requirement yourself, take a look at one of gems that will do that for you, personally I recommend PaperTrail:
https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

Answer (score 0):

A simple modification:

Instead of creating a new record in the product table, you could instead maintain a table called ProductChanges, with the columns "field", "from", "to". When the price is updated from 12 to 8, you could create a record with the values (product_id="" field="price", from=12, to=8).

Comment: When I edit the price 8 to 80 in the next time,I think the 'field' and 'to=8 ,from =8 'are data redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is, I would create another table (I'll call `changes`) with the columns

**id (PK), prod_id (FK), title, price, updated_at**

and each time I update the main table I would copy the current values in the main table into the `changes` table. You don't need the `created_at` and `edition` columns since the former is not subject to change and the it's easy to find the latter with a simple query in this changes table.